# NSTrackingArea with fullscreen window/view

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, nsview

I'm trying to install a NSTrackingArea into a fullscreen view in order to get mouse moved events.

However, whenever I do, I get an assertion error.  I've searched the web, but have not been able to find any leads.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_NSFullScreenWindow _setTrackingRect:inside:owner:userData:useTrackingNum:install:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.25/AppKit.subproj/NSWindow.m:3944
```

Here's the code that sets up the tracking area (x=1024, y=768):

```
    cocoaWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, x,y)
                                              styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask
                                                backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                  defer:NO];
    glView = [[WLMacGLView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0,  x,y) pixelFormat:[WLMacGLView defaultPixelFormat]];
    [glView setCocoaController:self];

    //add the glView as a subview of the window's content view
    [[cocoaWindow contentView] addSubview:glView];
    NSRect r = [glView frame];
    NSTrackingArea *track = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:r options: NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingActiveWhenFirstResponder | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow
                                   owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [glView addTrackingArea:track];
    [glView enterFullScreenMode:[NSScreen mainScreen] withOptions:nil];
    [glView createContext];
```

The assertion happens right after the call to enterFullScreenMode: withOptions:

Anyone got any ideas?  Is this not the approach I should be taking to get mouse moved events in a fullscreen window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question turned out to be a bug in my own code.

When initializing the NSTrackingArea, I was passing in the wrong object for owner.  The proper thing to pass was the NSView.  With that corrected, all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track mouse in the whole view, I think is will be easier to implement the `mouseDown:`, `mouseMoved:` and `mouseUp:` methods in order to get the mouse events.

Comment: Those methods are implemented, but they don't get called when the window is fullscreen.

Comment: There is sample application that you can take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/GeekGameBoard/index.html (it uses a NSView subclass not an OpenGL one).

Comment: Make sure you call `[[glView window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES]` if you want to use `-mouseMoved:`.